# Split string and print the value of string separately in autocad

Tags: c#, string, split, autocad

`534-W1A-R1` this is my file name and I want to split it so it prints like

```
Code=534 Phase=1 Zone=A
```

in my Autocad file.

Comment: That 1 is in between W and A

Comment: Use split : string input = 534-W1A-R1; string[] splitArray = input.Split(new char[] {"-"});

Answer (score 1):

You have different ways to do it. if you are sure about the format of the text you can just use this:

```
var str= "534-W1A-R1";
var parts=str.Split('-');
var code= parts[0];
var secondPart= parts[1];
var phase=secondPart.Substring(1,secondPart.Length-2);
var zone=secondPart[secondPart.Length-1];
```

You can also use Regex if it is more complicated.

Comment: format will be change according to project i mean the value of 1 will be two or three digit sometime.

Comment: give this a try.@Ajjags

Comment: Thanks @Rakitić +1 ;)

Comment: The split method overload that takes array of chars and returns array of tokens is bit easier to use, see related comment under the question

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis I also used split. take a look at line 2

Comment: If I remember well, one splits in two parts, other version in multiple parts. Might remember wrong though

Comment: @GeorgeBirbilis :O how do you split in 2 parts?! when you split("-") it will be 3 parts already

Answer (score 1):

The below split code should work:

```
string str = @"534-W1A-R1";

var split = str.Split('-');

string code = split.First();
string phase = new string(split.ElementAt(1).Skip(1).Take(1).ToArray());
string zone = new string(split.ElementAt(1).Skip(2).Take(1).ToArray());

string result = String.Format("Code={0} Phase={1} Zone={2}", code, phase, zone);
Console.WriteLine(result);
```

Output:

```
Code=534 Phase=1 Zone=A
```

Answer (score 1):

Use the [`Substring()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aka44szs(v=vs.110).aspx) method.

```
string input = "534-W1A-R1";
string sub = input.Substring(0, 3);
string sub2 = input.Substring(5, 1);
string sub3 = input.Substring(6, 1);
Console.WriteLine("Code={0} Phase={1} Zone={2}", sub, sub2, sub3);
```

Output:

```
Code=534 Phase=1 Zone=A
```

Comment: Thanks for the edit, we also missed the second part which I just corrected ;)

Answer (score 0):

Using Regex

Edit: added some comments (pattern description)

```
var pattern = @"^(\d+)-[A-Z](\d+)([A-Z])-";
/* pattern description:
^(\d+)  group 1: one or more digits at the begining
-       one hyphen (literal)
[A-Z]   one alphabetic character
(\d+)   group 2: one or more digits
([A-Z]) group 3: one alphabetic character
-       one hyphen (literal)
*/
var input = "534-W1A-R1";
var groups = Regex.Match(input, pattern, RegexOptions.IgnoreCase).Groups;
var code = groups[1].Value;
var phase = groups[2].Value;
var zone = groups[3].Value;
```